# Calling methods from a different class on method_missing

Tags: ruby

I have a class that loads a collection and loads items into a collection based on a certain criteria

```
require_relative 'thing'
class Someclass
    def self.tings
       things=load_things()
    end
    def self.select_things(something)
       return things.select { |thing| thing.some_property == something }
    end
end
```

I would like to use method_missing instead of the direct defintions

```
require_relative 'thing'
class Someclass
    def self.method_missing(method, *args)
        things=load_things()
        if method == 'select_things'
            self.send("things.select { |thing| thing.some_property == args }")
        end
    end
end
```

However, this approach doesn't work and method_missing just outputs the code string. Is there a proper way to call a code from method_missing?

Thank you very much everyone in advance

Comment: Your `send` syntax is wrong, but there’s no need to use `send`. You can just use your previous code `return things.select { |thing| thing.some_property == something }` in `method_missing`.

Comment: I would recommend you to reconsider if `method_missing` really gives you any benefit. I tend to avoid because it can make tracking down code difficult. And especially in your case, you are saying `if method == "select_things"` why not just define `def select_things` instead?  `method_missing` is really used for cases when you want the method name to be totally dynamic, e.g. Rails' `find_by_<attribute>` is a good example. Also see https://emmanuelhayford.com/3-practical-uses-of-ruby-method-missing/ for some more examples.

Comment: @Mikhail _"such as `=` that can be passed"_ – can you give a more complete example? There's probably a solution, but I'm not sure which part is fixed and which part is going to be dynamic.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to solve two problems at once. `method_missing` allows your object to _respond_ to messages with arbitrary names. `send` allows your object to _send_ messages with arbitrary names. Although you can combine them, there's no need to do so. You can use `method_missing` and have a static implementation and you can use `send` from within a static method. You should focus one one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your `method_missing` implementation:

1. The method name is given as a *symbol*, not as a string:

   ```
   def self.method_missing(method, *args)
     if method == :select_things
       # ...
     end
   end
   ```
2. You have to call `super` if you don't process the message yourself:

   ```
   def self.method_missing(method, *args)
     if method == :select_things
       # ...
     else
       super
     end
   end
   ```

If you don't call `super` your object is going to swallow any message without ever raising a `NoMethodError` and you'll have a very hard time understanding why your code isn't working.

In addition, you should also implement `respond_to_missing?` to return `true` for the messages you are responding to, e.g.:

```
def self.respond_to_missing?(method, include_all = false)
  [:select_things].include?(method) || super
end
```

The above gives you:

```
Someclass.respond_to?(:select_things) #=> true
```

Comment: Stefan, thank you very much for your help! So the respond_to is unavoidable, there is no way to have method_missing without it ?

Comment: @Mikhail well, if you don't implement `respond_to_missing?`, your class would say that it doesn't respond to `select_things` although it does. Why would you want that?

Comment: `method_missing` will work just fine without it. Maybe you'll learn about `respond_to_missing?` in the next lesson.